# Calendar Events Doesn't Load First Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, fullcalendar

I have one select list box in there 3 option value and last option value is `Calendar` , while i will click on calendar events doesn't load first time...

My code for Full calendar + events.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
         $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
             events: "json-events.php",
             loading: function(bool) { 
                if (bool) { 
                     $('#loading').show();
                }
                else {
                     $('#loading').hide();
                }
             },
          });
     });
  </script>
```

Comment: Have you got any log from console? Is events script working correctly?

Comment: LOL, thanks to your misspelling of "calendar" with "calender" I just learned that *calenders* are hard pressure rollers used to form sheets of material.

Answer (score 2):

i had a similar problem:
so i rerendered the calendar:

```
if (bool) {
   $('#loading').show();
    setTimeout(function(){
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
        },1);

   }
```

hope this works for your setting too.

Comment: I had an issue where I was loading a view using ajax and a transition effect. The calendar wouldn't render correctly on the first load so this solved it. Thanks!